# Retry UseCase Function with Clear Architecture

Tags: flutter, dart, clean-architecture

I'm trying to implement a function, that re-runs the last UseCase I've been running. Same arguments, just repeat last UseCase execution. How would I go about doing this?

I would also like to have a function that retries last failed UseCase, for example, repeat last UseCase that returned a specific Error/Exception like 'NoInternetException'.

Is there a nice solution for something like that? Any ideas?

My UseCases are defined like this:

```
abstract class UseCase<Type, Params> {
  Future<Either<Failure, Type>> call(Params params);
}
```

Been googling, didn't really find much.